# Gradient Question-Linear Regression

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-programming

When discussing linear regression, we discuss the error of the out of sample data prediction. That is, $$ E_{\operatorname{out}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\boldsymbol{w}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}_n-\,\,y_n)^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_nx_n -y_n)^2  $$ and letting $\boldsymbol{x}_n^{T}$ be each row of a matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$, and each $y_n$ be a component of a vector $\boldsymbol{y}$, we may write $$E_{\operatorname{out}} = \frac{1}{N} || \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{y} ||^2$$

We want to minimize this, so we take the gradient with respect to each $w_i \in \boldsymbol{w}$. That is, $$\nabla E_{\operatorname{out}} = \frac{2}{N} \boldsymbol{X}^{T} (\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{y} )$$.. Now the question here is, why is it $\boldsymbol{X}^{T}$ as opposed to $\boldsymbol{X}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not look right.  It should be

$$
\frac{2}{N} X^T (X w-y).
$$

The question of why it is $X^T (Xw -y)$ instead of its transpose remains, however.   It just depends on whether you want to define the gradient as a row or column vector.

Comment: My professor gave an inaudible reason for this, I couldn't quite understand, but it didn't seem that the choice was arbitrary.

Comment: The question isn't regarding the whole expression, just why the gradient yields $\boldsymbol{X}^{T}$ instead of $\boldsymbol{X}$

Comment: For one thing, $X(Xw-y)$ is not generally well-defined since the number of columns in $X$ is not generally the same as the number of elements in $(Xw-y)$.  Another way of thinking about it is that your $E_\text{out}$ is $(w^T X^T - y^T) (X w - y)/N.$